# method called from outside main method not executed

Tags: java

In the following code, the method deposit or withdraww or deposit or transfer is not being executed completely when called from main method. I am a basic java learner and this is one of my first programs. Can you please help me with the same?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Bank {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String name, no;
    static int accNo, accNo1, bal, amt, a, tra, acct, bal1, bala, acct2, ac1;

    Bank(String name, String no, int accNo, int accNo1, int bal, int bal1, int ac1) {
        this.name = name;
        this.no = no;
        this.accNo = accNo;
        this.bal = bal;
    }

    private Bank(String name, String no, int accNo, int accNo1, int bal, int amt, int a, int tra, int acct, int bal1, int bala, int acct2, int ac1) {
    }

    static void deposit() {
        System.out.println("Enter the account to which amount is to be deposited");
        Scanner ac = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ac1 = ac.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter amount to deposit: (Enter in Multiples of Rs.500)");
        amt = input.nextInt();

        if (ac1 == accNo) {
            bal = bal + amt;
            System.out.println("Acct no:" + accNo);
            System.out.println("Balance:Rs. " + bal);
        } else if (ac1 == accNo1) {
            bal1 = bal1 + amt;
            System.out.println("Acct no:" + accNo1);
            System.out.println("Balance:Rs. " + bal1);
        } else if ((acct2 != accNo) || (acct2 != accNo1)) {
            System.out.println("Account no not registered");
        }
    }

    static void withdraw() {
        System.out.println("Enter the account from which amount is to be withdrawn");
        Scanner ac3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ac2 = ac3.nextInt();
        if (ac2 == accNo) {
            System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw");
            amt = input.nextInt();
            bal = bal - amt;
            System.out.println("Acct no:" + accNo);
            System.out.println("Balance:Rs. " + bal);
        } else if (ac2 == accNo1) {
            System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw");
            amt = input.nextInt();
            bal1 = bal1 - amt;
            System.out.println("Acct no:" + accNo1);
            System.out.println("Balance:Rs. " + bal1);
        } else {
            if ((acct2 != accNo) || (acct2 != accNo1)) {
                System.out.println("Account no not registered");
            }
        }
    }

    static void display() {

        System.out.println("Enter the account number for balance:");
        bala = input.nextInt();
        if (bala == accNo) {
            System.out.println("Account No:" + accNo);
            System.out.println("The balance in the account is Rs." + bal);

        } else if (bala == accNo1) {
            System.out.println("Account No:" + accNo1);
            System.out.println("The balance in the account is Rs." + bal1);

        }
        if ((acct2 != accNo) || (acct2 != accNo1)) {
            System.out.println("Account number not registered!!");
        }
    }

    static void transfer() {

        System.out.println("Enter the account number to which amount is to be transferred:");
        acct2 = input.nextInt();
        if (acct2 == accNo) {
            System.out.println("Enter the amount to be transferred:");
            tra = input.nextInt();
            if (bal < tra - 500) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds. Minimum balance to be maintained in your account is Rs.500");
            } else {
                bal = bal - tra;
                bal1 = bal1 + tra;
            }
        } else if (acct2 == accNo1) {
            if (bal1 < tra - 500) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds. Minimum balance to be maintained in your account is Rs.500");
            } else {
                bal1 = bal1 - tra;
                bal = bal + tra;
            }

        } else {
            if ((acct2 != accNo) || (acct2 != accNo1)) {
                System.out.println("Account No not registered !!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to personal account netbanking!");
        System.out.println("To become a registered user of netbanking, kindly enter the following details");
        System.out.println("Please enter your Full Name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Contact Number:");
        Scanner no1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String no = no1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the first  Account Number ");
        Scanner acc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int accNo = acc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second  Account Number ");
        Scanner acc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int accNo1 = acc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Amount to be deposited in the fist account");
        Scanner amt1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int bal = amt1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Amount to be deposited in the second account");
        Scanner amt2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int bal1 = amt2.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Thank you for registering");
        System.out.println("Kindly make a note of your username: 'admin' and password: 'admin'");
        System.out.println("Please enter the user name: ");
        String u = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the password: ");
        BufferedReader p = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String y = input.nextLine();
        Bank b1 = new Bank(name, no, accNo, accNo1, bal, amt, a, tra, acct, bal1, bala, acct2, ac1);
        if ("admin".equals(u) && "admin".equals(y)) {


            int menu;
            System.out.println(" Welcome " + name);
            boolean quit = false;
            do {

                System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
                System.out.println("1. Balance Enquiry");
                System.out.println("2. Deposit Amount");
                System.out.println("3. Withdraw Amount ");
                System.out.println("4. Transfer Amount");
                System.out.println("5. Exit");
                menu = input.nextInt();

                switch (menu) {
                    case 1:
                        b1.display();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        b1.deposit();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        b1.withdraw();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        b1.transfer();
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        quit = true;
                        break;
                }
            } while (!quit);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG!! Indent this code... asap!!

Comment: Please tell us what your actual problem is.

Comment: @codeMan If you think indenting the code would make it more readable/improve the question, you are able to do it yourself using the 'edit' link on the question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have two constructors and when you call "new Bank", the empty constructor is called. Copy the assignments from the first constructor into the second or just call the good constructor from the empty one.

---

**Edit:**

You have this:

```
Bank(String name, String no, int accNo, int accNo1, int bal, int bal1, int ac1) {
    this.name = name;
    this.no = no;
    this.accNo = accNo;
    this.bal = bal;
}

private Bank(String name, String no, int accNo, int accNo1, int bal, int amt, int a, int tra, int acct, int bal1, int bala, int acct2, int ac1) {
}
```

And you should have (at least) this:

```
Bank(String name, String no, int accNo, int accNo1, int bal, int bal1, int ac1) {
    this.name = name;
    this.no = no;
    this.accNo = accNo;
    this.bal = bal;
}

private Bank(String name, String no, int accNo, int accNo1, int bal, int amt, int a, int tra, int acct, int bal1, int bala, int acct2, int ac1) {
    this.name = name;
    this.no = no;
    this.accNo = accNo;
    this.bal = bal;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand what you are saying. Don't I have only one constructor?

Comment: Look at this code: 
----
    private Bank(String name, String no, int accNo, int accNo1, int bal, int amt, int a, int tra, int acct, int bal1, int bala, int acct2, int ac1) {
    }
----

It is called the private constructor. And it is being called by your main method. And it does nothing, while it is supposed to do the same as another Bank constructor (just above the private one).

Comment: thanks a lot.... i removed the unused second constructor and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your problem is that the code is throwing an exception somewhere and that's it's only partially running.  Try (no pun intended) putting a try catch block around your code:

```
public static main(String args[]) {

    try {

         // you existing code goes here

    } catch (Throwable t) {

        System.out.println(t);

    }

}
```

This will at least tell you what the problem is.

Comment: The code fails on comparison, and skips an expected brunch. No exception thrown.

Comment: I tried adding try catch, but it still returns to menu on choosing deposit or balance or any other option. Without executing the method completely, the menu choices are displayed again